# PrimeFaces p:ajax event=“change” not fired

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to generate second selecOneMenu content when the user triggers an event on the first selecOneMenu, but it doesn't work.

Here is the navigation rule in face-config.xml

```
 <navigation-rule>
     <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{contact_.inscription_fournisseur}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>xhtml/Inscription_user.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

here is my index page : whene i click on  *S'inscrire* it initiates the first list and redirects me to Inscription_user.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

  <!--  <link href="${request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ao.js" />


    <h:head>
        <title><h:outputText value="#{En_Fr.titre_page_index_fr}"/></title>
    </h:head>
    <body class="box_center" >
        <div style="border:0px #888 solid; margin-top:40px; margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%">


        <div class="box_fournisser">

        <div class="titre_site" style="text-align:right">Accs fournisseur</div>

<div class="pwd_oublie font-label" style="text-align:right; color: #666;">  <label>Mot de passe oublié</label></div><div class="pwd_oublie font-label" style="text-align:right; text-decoration: underline;">  
<label><h:form>
              <h:commandLink action="#{contact_.inscription_fournisseur}"  styleClass="pwd_oublie font-label" style="text-align:left; margin-left: 15px; text-decoration: underline;" >
              S'inscrire
              </h:commandLink>
              </h:form>
              </label>
          </div></div>

    <div  class="statistic_ background_site_unselected  "  ><label class="nombre_statistic">1236</label><label class="label_statistic">appel d'offre</label></div>
    <div  class="statistic_ background_site_unselected  " style="top:10%" ><label class="nombre_statistic">15985</label><label class="label_statistic">demande de devis</label></div>
    <div  class="statistic_ background_site_unselected " style="top:15%" ><label class="nombre_statistic">4859</label><label class="label_statistic">visite par moi</label></div></div>



</body>
        </html>
```

my Inscription_user.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<link href="../css/inscription.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <h:head>
        <title><h:outputText value="#{En_Fr.titre_page_index_fr}"/></title>
    </h:head>
    <body>
<div></div>
  <f:view>   
            <h:form>
            <h:messages>d :</h:messages>
          <div   class="ligne_inscription" >
 <div class="label_inscription">Direction</div>
<div>
<p:selectOneMenu effect="fade" value="#{contact_.organisme.selectedDirection}" style="width:110;">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="0"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{contact_.organisme.directions}" var="direction" itemLabel="#{direction.direction}" itemValue="#{direction.idDirection}"/>
<p:ajax update="lstfonct" listener="#{contact_.organisme.initFonction}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
                </div></div>


                           <div   class="ligne_inscription" >
<div class="label_inscription">Fonction</div><div>



<p:selectOneMenu effect="fade" value="#{contact_.organisme.selectedFonction}" id="lstfonct">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="0"/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{contact_.organisme.fonctions}" var="fonction" itemLabel="#{fonction.fonction}" itemValue="#{fonction.idEmploi}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>       
</div></div>  


    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Valider"  action="#{contact_.inscription_choix_alerte()}"  />         

            </h:form>

</f:view>  

    </body>
</html>
```

here is my bean Contact_

```
package beans;
// Generated 23 oct. 2012 21:51:42 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import Dao.Emploi_dao;




/**
 * Contact generated by hbm2java
 */

@ManagedBean(name="contact_")
@RequestScoped

public class Contact_  implements java.io.Serializable {


     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 493917875769565440L;

     @ManagedProperty(value="#{organisme_}")
     private Organisme_ organisme;


    public Organisme_ getOrganisme() {
        return organisme;
    }


    public void setOrganisme(Organisme_ organisme) {
        this.organisme = organisme;
    }




    public String inscription_fournisseur() {
        organisme.setDirections(Emploi_dao.List_direction());
        return "success";
    }



}
```

my bean organisation_

```
package beans;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


import Dao.Activite_dao;
import Dao.Emploi_dao;
import Dao.Organisme_dao;
import hibernate.Activite;
import hibernate.Adresse;
import hibernate.Emploi;
import hibernate.Organisme;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;



/**
 *
 *
 */

@ManagedBean (name="organisme_")
@RequestScoped
public class Organisme_  implements java.io.Serializable  {
     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4579411552477526993L;


     private List<Emploi> directions = new ArrayList <Emploi>(0);
     private List<Emploi> fonctions = new ArrayList <Emploi>(0);
     private String SelectedDirection;
     private String SelectedFonction;



     public List<Emploi> getDirections() {
        return directions;
    }



    public void setDirections(List<Emploi> directions) {
        this.directions = directions;
    }



    public List<Emploi> getFonctions() {
        return fonctions;
    }



    public void setFonctions(List<Emploi> fonctions) {
        this.fonctions = fonctions;
    }



    public String getSelectedDirection() {
        return SelectedDirection;
    }



    public void setSelectedDirection(String selectedDirection) {
        SelectedDirection = selectedDirection;
    }



    public String getSelectedFonction() {
        return SelectedFonction;
    }



    public void setSelectedFonction(String selectedFonction) {
        SelectedFonction = selectedFonction;
    }



    public void initFonction()
    {
        System.out.println("------------debut-----------");
         fonctions=Emploi_dao.List_fonction(SelectedDirection);


    }




}
```

there is one solution by removing the initialization on the directions list from the method  inscription_fournisseur() on the contact_ bean class, and make it in the default constructor of the organisation_ bean class, in this case it works, but I don't prefer this solution, I prefer the first scenario, please help me.

Comment: I don't see an `<h:form/>` anywhere in your view. Did you purposely omit that bit or it's actually not present in your code?

Comment: no it present in my code (just for not posting a lot of code lines)

Comment: It's a very important piece to the entire puzzle, it's absence or presence means a lot to the eventual solution. Do you have more than one and are they nested?

Comment: ok il will change my post, i will post my entire xhtml page

Comment: i have post the important part of the code , thanks for your response

Comment: Is it by accident that you have `<h:selectOneMenu effect...>` with `<p:ajax>`? It could pretty well be the cause of the problem, as such attribute doesn't exist in that tag. Also, try not timid tags, using either the JSF ones, or the PrimeFaces ones and leave us the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

1. youre using the wrong namespace  `<f:ajax>` should be `<p:ajax>`
2. Instead u should change `update` to update what you want and set the selected value in a method defined by the `listener` to change your other selectMenu's data

see the [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf)

Comment: i have post the entire code, actually i am using p:ajax tag, and even if i delete teh change event it not working, thank for responding

Comment: @NickHol 1. Namespace is right, given that OP on fact used `<h:selectOneMenu>`. 2. There is `change` event, but as in showcase it can be omitted, as it's basically the default one.

Comment: @skuntsel His topicname states : p:ajax, then his first post was using f:ajax..
is code is just really unreadable. Weird that you downvote me for that..

solarie,  remove '_' from youre class names, show us what 'SelectedDirection' is (why capital S?) and put a <h:messages> at top of your page to see if it displays any errors. Since you should be atleast able to see the system out.

Comment: @NickHol I know that OP posted extravagantly unformatted code with no respect to java naming conventions. But still your points, especially the second one, is plain wrong.

Comment: thanks for your response, i edit my post to make it more readable, waiting for your suggrestion.